# Merge two array list into a TreeMap in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, treemap, treeset

I want to combine these two text files

Driver details text file:

```
AB11; Angela
AB22; Beatrice
```

Journeys text file:

```
AB22,Edinburgh ,6
AB11,Thunderdome,1
AB11,Station,5
```

And I want my output to be only the names and where the person has been. It should look like this:

```
Angela
  Thunderdone
  Station

Beatrice
  Edinburgh
```

Here is my code. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but i'm not getting the right output.

```
ArrayList<String>  names = new ArrayList<String>();
TreeSet<String>  destinations = new TreeSet<String>();

public TaxiReader() {

    BufferedReader brName = null;
    BufferedReader brDest = null;

    try {

        // Have the buffered readers start to read the text files
        brName = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("taxi_details.txt"));
        brDest = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("2017_journeys.txt"));

        String line = brName.readLine();
        String lines = brDest.readLine();

        while (line != null && lines != null ){

            // The input lines are split on the basis of certain characters that the text files use to split up the fields within them
            String name [] = line.split(";");
            String destination [] = lines.split(",");

            // Add names and destinations to the different arraylists
            String x = new String(name[1]);
            //names.add(x);

            String y = new String (destination[1]);
            destinations.add(y);


            // add arraylists to treemap
            TreeMap <String, TreeSet<String>> taxiDetails = new TreeMap <String, TreeSet<String>> ();
            taxiDetails.put(x, destinations);

            System.out.println(taxiDetails);

            // Reads the next line of the text files
            line = brName.readLine();
            lines = brDest.readLine();

        }

     // Catch blocks exist here to catch every potential error
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         // Finally block exists to close the files and handle any potential exceptions that can happen as a result
        } finally {
            try {
                if (brName != null)
                    brName.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

}


public static void main (String [] args){
    TaxiReader reader = new TaxiReader();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: May want to look into [`BufferedReader#lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) and [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading 2 files in parallel, I don't think that's gonna work too well. Try reading one file at a time.

Also you might want to rethink your data structures.

The first file relates a `key` "AB11" to a `value` "Angela". A map is better than an arraylist:

```
Map<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>();

String key = line.split(",")[0]; // "AB11"
String value = line.split(",")[1]; // "Angela"
names.put(key, value)
names.get("AB11"); // "Angela"
```

Similarly, the second file relates a `key` "AB11" to multiple `values` "Thunderdome", "Station". You could also use a map for this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> destinations = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

String key = line.split(",")[0]; // "AB11"
String value = line.split(",")[1]; // "Station"

if(map.get(key) == null) {
    List<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();
    values.add(value);
    map.put(key, values);
} else {
    // we already have a destination value stored for this key
    // add a new destination to the list
    List<String> values = map.get(key);
    values.add(value);
}
```

To get the output you want:

```
// for each entry in the names map
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : names.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String name = entry.getValue();

    // print the name
    System.out.println(name);

    // use the key to retrieve the list of destinations for this name
    List<String> values = destinations.get(key);
    for(String destination : values) {
        // print each destination with a small indentation
        System.out.println("  " + destination);
    }
}
```